# Able to create a "generic" plug?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on a toy project in Phoenix which is essentially a multi-step ordering website.  On each step of the ordering process I want to ensure that the session variable for the previous session is set.  Currently I have a plug for each which is essentially a copy-paste of the same plug with different variables.

Here is a toy example of what the plug looks like

```
defmodule Project.Plugs.RequireDesign do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Phoenix.Controller

  alias Project.Router.Helpers

  def init(_params) do
  end

  def call(conn, _params) do
    case get_session(conn, :order_design) de
      nil ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, "You must select a design.")
        |> redirect(to: Helpers.order_path(conn, :design))
        |> halt()
      _ ->
        conn
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to create a generic plug which takes an atom for a session variable, a message to show in a flash and a path to redirect to?  I'd like to have one plug which takes those variables instead of creating the same plug over and over again.

Any thoughts? :)

**EDIT**: If anyone is interested in how I called my "generic" plug multiple times in the same controller, all I did was add a `when action in[:my_action]` to each of the different calls.  Basically I did

```
defmodule MyApp.Web.FooController do
  plug Foo, %{key: :order_design,
              message: "You must select a design.", 
              path: Helpers.order_path(conn, :design)
            } when action in [:my_action]

  ...
end
```

You can now use the plug multiple times for different actions in the controller.  I suppose you can also apply the plug if you use the inverse, `when not action in [:my_action]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary data into your plugs.

```
defmodule Foo do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(params) do
    params
  end

  def call(conn, %{key: key, message: message, path: path) do
    case get_session(conn, key) do
      nil ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, message)
        |> redirect(to: path)
        |> halt()
      _ ->
        conn
    end
  end
end
```

Then you actually pass that data in,

```
defmodule MyApp.Web.FooController do
  plug Foo, %{key: :order_design,
              message: "You must select a design.", 
              path: Helpers.order_path(conn, :design)
             }

  ...
end
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Is it possible to call it in the same controller with different arguments?  Sorry -- bit of an Elixir noob right now!

Comment: Scratch that, figured it out.  Thanks :)